# Prometheus actuator/prometheus interface inaccessible

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I deployed prometheus by yml file and configmap yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-config
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval:     15s
      evaluation_interval: 15s
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'spring'
        metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
        scrape_interval: 15s
        static_configs:
        - targets: ['10.98.84.247:8087'] --> this @ip Of my deployment service
```

promotheus interface work and it shows my app is up 1/1 with no errors but i can"r acess to

```
http://10.98.84.247:8087/actuator/prometheus
```

i have added all dependenice neede i guess

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and the needed line in application.proprties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,prometheus
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
```

what im doing wrong ?